# How to delete files from local repo which were removed in remote repo without deleting untracked files

Tags: git, github, git-pull

Let's say i have the following files on my remote repo

```
file_a.py
file_b.py
```

And the following files in my synced local repo

```
file_a.py
file_b.py
ignored_important_file.py
```

Then i deleted `file_b.py` from remote repo, but when i do `git pull origin master` on my local machine i find that file_b.py is still there

How can i sync with remote repo deleting file_b but keeping important ignored files?

Comment: After `git pull`, `file_b.py` on local repo should be deleted as well. Looks like your remote repo still has this file.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs i checked the remote and local repos. They are both on the same branch, both on the same commit. if i do `reset --hard`  on local repo file_b is still there

Comment: What does the output of `git status` look like at the moment?

Comment: Seems like `git clean -f -x -n` can delete `file_b` but it is also killing ignored file, so this does not help

Comment: @chamila-c `# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me! I found the answer when tried to run `git clean -f -n`. This should remove all outdated files, but the delete list was empty. **But** if i run `git clean -f -n -x` where `-x` forces it to delete ignored files, i found that `file_b` was there. The git was ok, i was wrong. my `.gitignore` file looked like this

```
*.pyc
ignored_important_file.py
```

`file_b.py` was deleted as it should, but `file_b.pyc` remained untouched. I will just remove `*.pyc` from `.gitignore` and git will clean all remaining files for me.